# Store Struct in NSUserdefault swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Please I need help with this code, any assistance you can offer will be much appreciated.

I currently have a struct where that I use to save values before putting them in a table but when the app is restarted the values disappear, I have tried using nsuserdefaults (but nsuserdefaults does not save structs). Is there another method to save these values for even when the app is restarted??

*NSObject for SAVING TO NSUSERDEFAULTS*

```
import UIKit

var plannerMgr : plannerManager = plannerManager()

struct plan 
{
    var planName = "Un-Named"
    var planDescription = "Un-Described"
}

var pNameArray = NSMutableArray()
var pDescArray = NSMutableArray()

class plannerManager: NSObject {

    var plans = [plan]()


    func addPlan(pName: String, pDesc: String) {

        plans.append(plan(planName: pName, planDescription: pDesc))

        pNameArray.addObject(pName)
        pDescArray.addObject(pDesc)

        defaults.setObject(pNameArray, forKey: "pNameArray")
        defaults.setObject(pDescArray, forKey: "pDescArray")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }

}
```

*...Bit for GETTING FROM NSUSERDEFAULTS*

```
func getPlans() {
        if let tempArray1 = defaults.objectForKey("pNameArray") as? NSMutableArray {
            if (tempArray1.count > 0) {
                pNameArray = tempArray1
            }
        }

        if let tempArray2 = defaults.objectForKey("pDescArray") as? NSMutableArray {
            if (tempArray2.count > 0) {
                pDescArray = tempArray2
            }
        }

        for name1 in pNameArray {
            for desc1 in pDescArray {
                println("add Plan: name1 = \(name1) && desc1 = \(desc1) **")
                addPlan(name1 as! String, pDesc: desc1 as! String)
            }
        }
    }
```

My main issue is when i call the second func (getPlans) the app crashes, and the console mentions something about using a mutable method with an immutable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you save a mutable array to `NSUserDefaults`, you aren't guaranteed to get a mutable array back.

You need to get a `.mutableCopy()` of the array to ensure you are manipulating a *mutable* array.

```
if let tempArray1 = defaults.objectForKey("pNameArray") as? NSArray {
    if (tempArray1.count > 0) {
       pNameArray = tempArray1.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    }
}
```

Ensure to change this for both `tempArray1` and `tempArray2`.